# Parse JSON object to ChartJS using object.keys/object.values

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I'm trying to show data from a JSON file to ChartJS, however, my JSON structure is different to what I have seen in previous relatable questions. Check JSON below:

```
{
    "AAPL": [
        {
            "Q1": -26986,
            "Q2": -168099,
            "Q3": -137101,
            "Q4": -561990
        }
    ]
}
```

My code is an attempt to use the keys as labels and the values as data:

```
const xmlhttp4 = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url4 = 'https://api.npoint.io/ee3b3d406810c46c44e0';

xmlhttp4.open('GET', url4, true);
xmlhttp4.send();
xmlhttp4.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const datapoints = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        const data1 = datapoints[0]
        const barchart = document.getElementById('insider_positions_barchart').getContext('2d');
        const myBarChartAUD = new Chart(barchart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: Object.keys(data1),
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Net Activity',
                    data: Object.values(data1),
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 3
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    }
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        ticks: {
                            color: "white"
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    },
                    x: {
                        ticks: {
                            color: "white"
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, I'm guessing it's to do with how I'm calling the keys & values. Unless I should change the JSON structure perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, what for an output you want/expect, but I would have to say, if you want to display the quarters, you would have to get the values from here `data1["AAPL"][0];`, in this *specific* case.

**Here a short demo showcasing it:**

```js
let data1= { "AAPL": [{
    "Q1": -26986,
    "Q2": -168099,
    "Q3": -137101,
    "Q4": -561990 
}]};

// extracting only the needed data
let initialData = data1["AAPL"][0];

const data = {
  labels: Object.keys(initialData),
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 0',
      data: Object.values(initialData),
      backgroundColor: '#B0D3FF',
      barThickness: 20,
    }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: false,
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
    }
  }
};

new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div class="chart" style="height:184px">
<canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

> If this is not the desired output, please update your question, with more specifics